# jQuery selector: all links in first paragraph

Tags: jquery

I would like to apply doSomething() to every link of the first paragraph, using jQuery. This is what I have tried:

```
var firstParagraph = $("p").eq(0);
firstParagraph.$("a").doSomething();
```

What's the correct format? (P.S. Where can I learn about such selectors in more depth?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do:

```
var anchors = $('p:first a');
```

And there's more on selectors here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

```
firstParagraph.find("a").doSomething();
```

Also you might use shorthand:

```
var links = $("p:first a");
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do precise element selection is with the CSS selectors inside of `$(...)`. For instance, to hide all links in the first paragraph, do this

```
$('p:first-child a').hide();
```

But watch out, this will hide probably more than you want. It would affect the first paragraph in any `div`, for instance. If you want to hide only the first paragraph of the HTML body and not first paragraphs of subelements of the page, do either of these

```
$('body > p:first-child a').hide();  // first paragraph in body
$('p:first a').hide();               // first paragraph anywhere, but only once
```

These selectors (except `:first`) are jQuery agnostic. You can read about them [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Comment: `first` as in `p:first` is not standard.